# Go back to activity contentView after having set contentView to web view in android

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am creating a login where i utilise SAML and OAUTH2. To get a login token i need to open a web view where the user can put in his login credentials and pushes login. When he has done this, it redirects to a page with a SAML response. I need to be able to close the web view which i create when this respose is received. The problem right now is that i can't close the web view and get back the activity layout. Here is the code to i use to create the activity and show the web view:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    final WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    Button saxoLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saxologin);



    theLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Call private method

            setContentView(webview);






            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webview.postUrl(url, SAMLreq.getBytes());


            debug.append("does this even work?");
```

I have tried to use:`webview.setVisibility()` method and set it to invisible.
I have also tried to use`setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)`
But the first one just makes the viewer invisble and does not restore the activity layout and the ladder generates and error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont call setContentView twice. You should put your webview in activity_login file like:

```
<WebView android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

And when the theLogin Button clicked do your operations. Also dont forget set visibility for your webview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE).

hope it helps

Comment: Ty so much this was exactly what i needed :)